# "Get around" VS "Go around"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

To me both of the phrasal verbs: **get around somewhere** and **go around somewhere** mean **to go to different places** or **to go from one place to another in a place i.e. London**.

But the only difference that strikes me is that when you **get around somewhere** it means that you necessarily use a vehicle, but when you use **go around** it can imply that you either travel on foot or drive to somewhere.

Meanwhile, **get around** implies **travelling** which logically requires a vehicle, while **go around** alludes to just **going** which can imply travel or just a simple walk.

Do you confirm my take on the nuance between them or there is something else that I have to know?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that "get around" requires a vehicle, but I would say the nuance of it tends to be more **how** you travel rather than **where**. Something like "I can't get around very easily since my hip operation" would make sense, or "I get around on my moped." "Go around" would refer more to **where** though - "I'm going around all the shops in London this afternoon."

Comment: Therefore, @Showsni they can be used interchangeably; right?